Connecting .NET Core Application to Aurora MySQL via AWS RDS Proxy
I'm trying to connect my .NET API application to a MySQL database using an Amazon RDS Proxy, but I'm encountering difficulties. I've set up the RDS Proxy and MySQL instance. However, the connection doesn't seem to work as expected.
Environment:

.NET Core 6.0
MySQL 8.0
Amazon RDS Proxy

appsettings.json:
Old Connection String (Direct connect to MySQL)
{ "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "server=my-rds-instance.endpoint.amazonaws.com;port=3306;user id=dbuser;password=dbpassword;database=mydatabase;" } }
Proxy Connection String
{ "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=my-rds-proxy.endpoint.amazonaws.com;Port=3306;Database=mydatabase;Uid=proxyuser;Pwd=poxy+password;" } }
Program.cs:
services.AddDbContextPool<Context>(opts => { string connString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]; opts.UseMySql(connString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connString));}, 128);
Issues:
The connection to the database fails with a generic error.
I've checked the RDS Proxy endpoint and credentials and they are correct.
Questions:
Is there a specific configuration required to use RDS Proxy with MySQL in a .NET Core application?
Do I need to handle IAM authentication differently when using RDS Proxy?
Are there any additional steps or libraries needed to make this work?
Any help or guidance on how to correctly set up the connection would be greatly appreciated!

What error exactly you are seeing? Maybe it's credentials issue? Maybe Proxy can't authenticate to DB server?

I can connect it from EC2 which is hosted the .NET application so I don't think it's credentials issue (I'll add image above). When I checked the logs, it stops at Context DI and the application is showing 502.

#1 You need to attach the exact log error. Without log, no one can help you. #2 RDS Proxy  works exactly as a rds database. Try the connection with an IDE like dbeaver, heidi, or just a simple test like this. Share the results

After some research I could figure out that for RDS Proxy for some reason you should specify the exact version of your MySQL.

That's not only our issue: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1736
